# Patching new parents onto a Cover

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

In Demon, you can improve your covers by patching pieces of other peoples lives onto them.

For example if someone, a NPC named Fiona, was known as a cat lover, you might pact with her to take her relationship with her cats.
Then add it to your cover -- a middle aged bussiness man George, 
to make him be known as a cat lover.

Middle aged business man now has cats, Fiona  does not.
The god machine is more likely to be fooled by this new cover becasue it is stronger 
 -- everyone knows about George: He buys 3Kg of Catfood every week for the last 10 years, and his house reeks.
Definitely a real guy.

So that makes alot of sense when you are bargaining for some relationships.
Not so much for others.

Consider a NPC Phil: Phil's father killed himself when Phil was 4, and that has really left lasting effects 20 years on.

If a George, had pacted with Phil to take his realtionship/history of having a his father commit suicide, how does that go down?

George already has a NPC father. Does this kill (retroactively) George's father?
Does George get a second father (who is dead)? a step-father?
Presumably Phil still has a father, but now he never met him?

Answer (score 5):

If "George" is a patchwork cover, this just adds the details to "George's" history. Nobody knew anything about George's parents. He never mentioned them. Suddenly, word starts spreading that the reason George didn't talk about them is because his dad is actually dead of suicide. Isn't that tragic?

If "George" was a real person before the demon took over, then things get a little more complex. George was a real person, but then he ceased to be completely. "George" is a person whose story happens to match George's completely until he starts adding bits and pieces to it. Suddenly, instead of a happily retired cop dad, "George's" dad is a cop who killed himself when "George" was young.

Everyone forgets that Phil had a dad commit suicide. Everyone forgets that the happily retired cop was "George's" biological father. The Cop treats "George" as if "George" is as good as his son. The relationship there is rewritten in a way that makes sense to them. If they never met him, then they forget that he ever existed. If they did meet him, maybe they think he was "George's" step-father, or just a father-figure.

If someone starts digging into it, and discovers the discrepancy, then that is when "George's" Cover starts degrading.